# Elastic Search /: How can i filter the docs without a certain field

Tags: documentation, field, elasticsearch

I do search with queryString "datefield:[2012-09-12T12:00:00Z TO 2012-10-12T12:00:00Z]" by Java API.
But its response contains some docs without the field datefield.
How can I filter the docs without datefield ?

Comment: Do you have anything else in your query string? Are you sure it's just  a range query and not something like "datefield:[2012-09-12T12:00:00Z TO 2012-10-12T12:00:00Z] foo:bar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest that you build a [boolFilter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter.html) with a must clause with [range filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-filter.html) on datefield with your two dates and a must_not clause with [missing filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter.html) on dateField ?

Does it work?